# Trying to get gui menu to populate the "url =()" varible

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter

Hi eveyone hope you're well, I'm pretty new to python, but I'm trying to get an app made where the user inputs the URL and that URL will go into my code.
Is this the right route to do so.
The problem I have is I don't know what to put into =(text) function to enable the GUI to fill that out. So if they type [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in the gui box it fills in url=().

```py
    # GUI
    window = Tk()
    window.title = ("scraper")
    window.geometry('400x200')
    def button_command():
        text = entry1.get()
        print(text)
        return None
    
    entry1 = Entry(window, width=20)
    entry1.pack()
    Button(window, text="input", command=button_command).pack()
    
    window.mainloop()
      
    # url
    url =
```

Comment: At the moment, you are setting `text` to contain the value of the entry field. Why not add `global url` and `url = entry1.get()`  to the `button_command` function?

Answer (score 1):

From what i can understand, you're trying to get the text from the Entry.
You actually already got it with the `text = entry1.get()` line

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title = ("scraper")
window.geometry('400x200')

url = ''
def button_command():
    url = entry1.get()
    print(url)



entry1 = Entry(window, width = 20)
entry1.pack()
input_btn = Button (window, text="input", command=button_command)
input_btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Note. You should not use .pack() on the same line as the declaring of the Button. It disables some of the functionality